# NextJS ForwardRef(LinkComponent) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jestjs

[image]

Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?
Attempted to log "Warning: An update to ForwardRef(LinkComponent) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

```
When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
    at legacyBehavior (C:\Users\Ankit\Documents\ccportal-webapp\node_modules\next\src\client\link.tsx:274:7)
    at GoBackLink (C:\Users\Ankit\Documents\ccportal-webapp\components\common\GoBackLink.component.tsx:538:39)
    at p
    at div
    at section
    at main
    at PaymentCancelPage
    at WrapperComponent (C:\Users\Ankit\Documents\ccportal-webapp\node_modules\@cfaester\enzyme-adapter-react-18\dist\enzyme-adapter-utils\createMountWrapper.js:47:13)".



  at legacyBehavior (node_modules/next/src/client/link.tsx:274:7)
  at GoBackLink (components/common/GoBackLink.component.tsx:538:39)
      at p
      at div
      at section
      at main
      at PaymentCancelPage
  at WrapperComponent (node_modules/@cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18/dist/enzyme-adapter-utils/createMountWrapper.js:47:13)".
  at console.error (node_modules/@jest/console/build/BufferedConsole.js:127:10)
  at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:86:30)
  at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:7)
  at warnIfUpdatesNotWrappedWithActDEV (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27589:9)
  at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25508:5)
  at dispatchSetState (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17527:7)
  at setVisible (node_modules/next/src/client/use-intersection.tsx:125:56)
  at Window.cb (node_modules/next/src/client/request-idle-callback.ts:8:7)
  at Timeout.task [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:553:19)
```